# Resonating springs flywheel piston engine? Why not?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FyELVhRzXZyuoM0fcvZI6UvbApjnmQ_a/view?usp=drivesdk

Why couldn't you add two of these to either side of each piston and add a flywheel to the rotor?  Manual hand crank to start?  Aka the springs will contribute energy that is maintained by the flywheel that then perpetuates itself until the springs are exhausted or the load exceeds the capacity...  But that would be in cars and bikes right?  Why doesn't that work?

Comment: the video does not play ... sounds like you are describing a perpetual motion machine

Comment: Check out Dual Mass Flywheel.

Comment: what does an exhausted spring mean? do you know how springs work?

Comment: FWIW if you took two mainspring + hairspring assemblies from mechanical watches you could drive the reciprocating mass until the mainsprings ran down.   Take a look at Bacigalupi's  "Windup Girl" for a post-apocalyptic view of bio-spring-powered vehicles.

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking if this is not about perpetual motion.  If it is, then please go attempt it yourself.  Practitioners in engineering generally have faith in the laws of thermodynamics.  If you do not, I suspect you need more experience.

Answer (score 1):

[The video shows a weight on a spring being pushed and then bouncing left and right repeatedly]

Because if you make the spring push on a flywheel, or a piston, it stops bouncing.

It is like you spin a bike wheel with your hand, you see that it spins for a long time and you ask: why don't we connect it to a generator? Well, you can, but when the generator produces electricity it makes the wheel slow down and it won't spin for a long time.

Comment: I tried finding the other video showing a guy do it manually with a finger on a larger system, it's very easy, just push down a bit when it's on the downward cycle, the piston/flywheel combo just stores the energy, I guess mentioning the central mass has to have some weight to it is important, it would not work if the central mass was lightweight...

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jewSVEBkI_s

Comment: @JacobEdward when you connect a generator and a lightbulb to the flywheel, it will make the flywheel slow down. Then the guy will have to push harder to speed it back up.

Answer (score 0):

The video isn't showing any work, it's more akin to a pendulum.  Try to get work out of a pendulum and you end up with a weight hanging straight down.  You have to put energy into a system to take energy out.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jewSVEBkI_s

Comment: I believe that shows how to put energy into the system in order to get more out of it

Comment: I tried finding the other video showing a guy do it manually with a finger on a larger system, it's very easy, just push down a bit when it's on the downward cycle, the piston/flywheel combo just stores the energy, I guess mentioning the central mass has to have some weight to it is important, it would not work if the central mass was lightweight...

Comment: @JacobEdward no, you can't get energy out of a system via magnets, no matter how much someone says it's "resonating."  Every bit of energy you get out of something has to be put in first, and you have to put in more than you will get out.  Anything else is perpetual motion, and is a scam.

Comment: @JacobEdward this experiment isn't getting energy out of the system. Yes you can store energy in this kind of system but when you get the energy out then the system stops moving.

Comment: I'm not suggesting perpetual motion, I'm suggesting the spring has the energy from heat manufacturing, I said the springs exhaust

Comment: Imagine two studs with a weight hanging from a spring in the middle, if you push down on the weight with just a finger, it moves a little, but keep doing that on every downward cycle and the system will have a lot more energy than your finger taps

Comment: @JacobEdward, no, it will have less energy than the finger taps put into it.  You cannot extract energy from springs or from wood (unless you burn the wood).